# Delete only the row where both conditions is met

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

For example:

I have a table with shoppinglists that contains user_ids and list_names like this:

- user_id 1, list_name 1
- user_id 1, list_name 2
- user_id 2, list_name 1

Is there a way for me to delete only the row where user_id = 1 and list_id = 1, so that user_id 2, list_name 1 and user_id 1, list_name 2 stays?

I have used this code:

```
mysql_query("DELETE 
               FROM user_in_shoppinglists 
              WHERE (user_id = '$user_id' AND list_id = '$list_id')
            ")
```

But it removes the rows with both list_name 1 and list_name 2 for user_id 1.

Comment: that should work as expected are you sure of your variable values? helps to create the query in its own string then you can echo it

Comment: `$q="DELETE FROM user_in_shoppinglists WHERE (user_id = '$user_id' AND list_id = '$list_id')"; echo $q; exit();`

Comment: Yeah, user_id = 1 and list_id = 1. Will try the echo!

Comment: @Dagon : you should use `die($q)` which would print out the string and terminate the execution of the code, thus doing two commands at once.

Comment: @user1406062 well that's BS micro optermisation of debugging

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand sounds imposible to me, demo your db and code on: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: My fault, I wrote a statement where the program took a wrong turn...So the command was right! Should have gone to bed already...Sorry :S
Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: ok well i made a demo so may as well post: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1d8/1/0